# Terragrunt: Reading upstream varaibles

Tags: terragrunt

I'm trying to work out my AWS infrastructure and have the following structure:

```
regions
└── us-east-2_Ohio
    ├── terragrunt.hcl
    ├── variables.tf
    └── vpcs
        ├── myVPC
            ├── terragrunt.hcl
            ├── variables.tf
            └── vpc.tf
```

In the variables.tf at the `us-east-2_Ohio` level I have the provider and region set:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-2"
}
```

When I run terragrunt plan-all, I get prompted by the myVPC module for `provider.aws.region` by the vpc module. I'd like to have that be passed from the parent module, but no matter what I try it won't work.  Either it complains the block type is not expected or that the target module has not been applied. I even created a main.tf at the `us-east-2_Ohio` that only has

```
output "provider_region" {
  value = "us-east-2a"
}
```

and that didn't work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using Terragrunt, ideally you should stick to Terragrunt configuration in your Terragrunt hierarchy, and reference Terraform code in a separate repository. For an example of this, see the [Terragrunt infrastructure-live](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-live-example) and [Terragrunt infrastructure-modules](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt-infrastructure-modules-example) repositories. These demonstrate a few concepts that may help you make more sense of how to structure your code.

As demonstrated in the repositories I linked above, you would define the region in a `regions.hcl` file that would look like this:

```
locals {
  aws_region = "us-east-1"
}
```

In your module-level `terragrunt.hcl` (the `myVPC` module in your example), you'd have a block such as this one:

```
include {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}
```

This will include the `aws_region` variable and pass it to your Terraform module, where you can set it up in a `provider{}` block.